# How to cluster a rethinkdb database on docker with 3 different containers?

Tags: docker, rethinkdb

I am able to cluster a db on same machine by
`rethinkdb --port-offset 1 --directory rethinkdb_data2 --join localhost:29015`

I have tried to join the cluster with
`docker run -p 3003:8080 -d rethinkdb rethinkdb --port-offset 1 --join localhost:29015` but not succeeded.

From the rethinkdb document it mentioned that it can be done by `rethinkdb --join IP_OF_FIRST_MACHINE:29015 --bind all`

Rethinkkdb document link - https://rethinkdb.com/docs/start-a-server/#a-rethinkdb-cluster-using-multiple-machines